# Searching over related tables in Laravel

Tags: php, orm, laravel

I'm trying to perform a LIKE-query with Laravel over several tables which are tied together by has_one-relationships: A Product has one Category and one Company. My LIKE-search should return a product if the query string matches product->name or if it matches product->category->name or if it matches product->company->name.
What would be an elegant way to achieve this?

**products**
| id | category_id | company_id |      name       |
|  1 |           1 |          1 | Television X345 |
|  2 |           2 |          1 | Radio Y234      |

**companys**
| id |     name      |
|  1 | Super Company |
|  2 | Hero Inc.     |

**categories**
| id |     name      |
|  1 | Television    |
|  2 | Radio         |

Comment: I suppose you can go with Eloquent Constaint callback or defining scope query function with inner join defined inside. Did u tried something?

Comment: Puh - could you give me a push to the right direction? Heard something about inner join, don't know Eloquent Constaint callback... Many thanks!!

Comment: Hmmm you can start by reading here (http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent). then try some code just to familiarize with its logic...and edit here or a new question with code sample in case you won't find the right way